# initializing spritekit object with enum value for Image Name property

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Most of the SpriteKit code I've written so far just has a few objects so I put all the game logic in the GameScene. Now I am working on something more complex and I am trying to separate some of the objects into their own classes. How can I initialize the `Orbita` class below so that the `simpleDescription` string is used for the `ImageName` of the `SKSpriteNode` in `GameScene`?

```
class Orbita  {

var orbita : SKSpriteNode

init(orbita: SKSpriteNode) {
    self.orbita = orbita
    physics ()

}

func physics  ()  {
    orbita.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: orbita.frame.size.width/2)
    orbita.physicsBody?.friction = 0
   orbita.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    orbita.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    orbita.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
    orbita.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    orbita.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(4, -4))

}

enum OrbitaType: Int  {

    case firstPlanet = 0, secondPlanet, thirdPlanet

    func simpleDescription()->String    {
        switch self {

        case .firstPlanet:
            return "green"

        case .secondPlanet:
            return "red"

        case .thirdPlanet:
            return "yellow"
        }
    }
  }}
```

**UPDATE**

This is what I've been able to do so far. I decided to make a number of changes

```
class Orbita  {

var sprite : SKSpriteNode
var orbitaType : OrbitaType

init(orbita: SKSpriteNode) {
    self.orbita = orbita
    physics ()

}

    init(orbitaType: OrbitaType, gameScene: GameScene) {
    self.orbitaType = orbitaType
    sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: orbitaType.simpleDescription())

    sprite.name = orbitaCategoryName
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(3*gameScene.frame.size.width/4, 3*gameScene.frame.size.height/4)

    sprite.zPosition = 10
    gameScene.addChild(sprite)

    physics()

}


func physics  ()  {
    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: sprite.frame.size.width/2)
    sprite.physicsBody?.friction = 0
   sprite.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    sprite.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    sprite.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
    sprite.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    sprite.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(4, -4))

}

enum OrbitaType: Int  {

    case firstPlanet = 0, secondPlanet, thirdPlanet

    func simpleDescription()->String    {
        switch self {

        case .firstPlanet:
            return "green"

        case .secondPlanet:
            return "red"

        case .thirdPlanet:
            return "yellow"
        }
    }
  }}
```

In the `GameScene` class I added the following:

```
var newOrbita = Orbita(orbitaType: 0, gameScene: self)
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Orbita' with an argument list of type '(orbitaType: Int, gameScene: GameScene)'
```

Also, how can I add `newOrbita` as a class variable of `GameScene` since I am using `GameScene` as an argument?

Comment: Your error pertains to `Ball`, but there is no mention of Ball in the code.

Comment: sorry about that, I got the code mixed with some commented stuff, I just made the correction. I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`orbitaType` parameter is an `OrbitaType`, not an `Int`. You'll need to pass something like `Orbita(orbitaType: .firstPlanet, ...`.

Comment: I guess I have to do some `rawValue` conversion or so to pass `Int`. How is this done?

Comment: You can create `OrbitaType(rawValue: ...)`. Just curious, why do you need to pass an Int? Usually using enum constants by name is preferred since it's more readable.

Comment: how can I add `newOrbita` as a class variable of `GameScene` since I am using `GameScene` as an argument?

Comment: Why are you passing it as an argument? It seems there's no need. Makes sense for the scene to own the object.

Comment: In the `init` I add the sprite as a child. That's the main reason. As for the position, I can easily work around that.

Comment: no, you just have either to define
`init(Int:GameScene)`
or call
`Orbita(orbitaType: OrbitaType.firstPlanet, gameScene: self)`

but why do you pass the gameScene, anyway?

I'd create a `class OrbitaGameScene: GameScene`, and an `class OrbitaSprite: SKSprite` (for the `init` and `physics` methods)
then call the `addChile(OrbitaSprite(type: .first))` from there.
to use the numbers, make the `OrbitaType` conform to `CaseIterable` and use something like `OrbitaType.allCases.enumerated()` to get the all `(Int,OrbitaType)` pairs.

Answer (score 0):

To access anything from a separate class, you have to create an instance of that class:
In gameScene:

```
let orbitaInstance = Orbita() //let instanceName = classYouWantToAccess()
```

Then, inside of any function:

```
let image = SKSpriteNode(image: orbitaInstance.simpleDescription) // instanceOfClassYouAreAccessing.nameOfFunctionOrVariableYouAreAccessing
```

Hope this helped and good luck.